# Iterating through list and getting even and odd numbers

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, enumerate

yet one more exercise that I seem to have a problem with. I'd say I've got it right, but Python knows better.

The body of the task is:

> Write a function that takes a list or tuple of numbers. Return a
> two-element list, containing (respectively) the sum of the
> even-indexed numbers and the sum of the odd-indexed numbers. So
> calling the function as even_odd_sums([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]) ,
> you’ll get back [90, 120] .

My code is:

```
def even_odd_sums(sequence):
    sum_list = []
    for i, v in enumerate(sequence):
        if i % 2 == 0:
           sum_list = sum_list.insert(0, sum(v))
        else:
           sum_list = sum_list.insert(1, sum(v))
    return sum_list

print(even_odd_sums([10,20,30,40,50,60]))
```

the result is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-14518295929c> in <module>
----> 1 print(even_odd_sums([10,20,30,40,50,60]))

<ipython-input-59-51fcb6e9a115> in even_odd_sums(sequence)
      3     for i, v in enumerate(sequence):
      4         if i % 2 == 0:
----> 5            sum_list = sum_list.insert(0, sum(v))
      6         else:
      7            sum_list = sum_list.insert(1, sum(v))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried to find the solution on Google, I tried other ways to solve this task ("for i in range(len(sequence)), but I just can't solve non-iterable object problem

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: because `v` is a single value coming from iterating the list, so you can not pass it to `sum`, it requires a sequence to be passed, not a single value..

Comment: so I have to keep adding values to the new list so it'd be iterable and not a single value?

Comment: "I'd say I've got it right, but Python knows better." - In your own words, what do you think `v` will be, each time through the loop? What do you think should happen, if you pass that to `sum`? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `sum` takes an iterable, not a number. So, with your loop-approach, you could just keep adding to the proper sum:

```
def even_odd_sums(sequence):
    sum_list = [0, 0]
    for i, v in enumerate(sequence):
        sum_list[i % 2] += v
    return sum_list
```

Or, you can do the much simpler summation of the appropriate slices:

```
def even_odd_sums(sequence):
    return [sum(sequence[::2]), sum(sequence[1::2])]
```

Comment: The second approach is so simple and neat i can't help but wonder why didn't I think about it in the first place. Is it okay for a beginner?

Comment: Sure, it's ok :) I guess graduation from the manual looping approach to such concise solutions comes naturally as you get more familiar with all the tools a language puts at your disposal. I would note however, that algorithmically, the slice approach is worse because it has `O(N)` space complexity (because the slices create in-memory lists) whereas the loop approach has `O(1)` space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest method. Use slicing and indexing.

```
def even_odd_sums(lists):
    return [sum(lists[::2]),sum(lists[1::2])]
print(even_odd_sums([10,20,30,40,50,60]))
```

Comment: Write a function that takes a list or tuple of numbers. Return the result of alter-
nately adding and subtracting numbers from each other. So calling the func-
tion as plus_minus([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]) , you’ll get back the result of
10+20-30+40-50+60 , or 50 . 

--------------- How would I make this one? Can I approach with the same method you wrote?

Comment: Yes, you can. ```return [sum(lists[::2])-sum(lists[1::2])]```@PreacherBaby

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to use slicing and indexing. It is a great tool we all tend to forget to use.

```
def even_odd_sums(lists):
    return [sum(lists[::2]),sum(lists[1::2])]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
def even_odd_nums(sequence):
return [sum([item for index, item in enumerate(sequence) if index % 2 == 0]), sum([item for index, item in enumerate(sequence) if index % 2 != 0])]
```